# r function to compute the mean for values in a list

Tags: r, average

I have an r object that stores 6 values as shown below.

```
  acc1[[1]]$overall[1]
  0.9657
  acc1[[2]]$overall[1]
  0.96
  acc1[[3]]$overall[1]
  0.96
  acc1[[4]]$overall[1]
  0.94
  acc1[[5]]$overall[1]
  0.96
  acc1[[6]]$overall[1]
  0.95
```

I am curious to know if there is an efficient way to compute the mean of these values. I tried `sapply(acc1$overall[1], mean)` and it did not work. Any tips or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: `mean(unlist(acc1))` should also work. This ofcourse assumes that the structure in the list is not more complex than the example you give here.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi, & Paul, that worked.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi , thank Zheyuan will do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to 李哲源ZheyuanLi, & Paul, both solutions worked , however I added ,`na.rm = TRUE` to remove any missing values.

```
mean( sapply(acc1, function (x) x$byClass[4]),na.rm = TRUE )
```